Some installed formulae are deprecated or disabled. You should find replacements for the following formulae: openssl@1.1
Please help me to resolve this issue
I tried to search for that particular file but didn't find it.
I tried brewhelp but wasn't able to resolve it.
Anymore suggest rather than brew help or brew doctor?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!
